# Inconveniente con Combobox anidados en Jsp (Java Web)

Tags: java, jsp

Cordial saludo agradezco la colaboración que me puedan brindar, con el siguiente inconveniente que se me presenta al momento de vincular dos combobox anidados en la herramienta JSP, el primer combobox me trae diferentes herramientas de programación, bases de datos o tecnología (C++, SQL Server, Excel, YouTube, C, Word) y en el otro cuadro combinado me debe de traer los videos correspondientes asociados a cada una de las herramientas mencionadas anteriormente , cuando el código que tengo es el siguiente me llena de manera adecuada el primer combobox, es decir de las herramientas, pero cuando incluyo el código que esta dentro de lo que aparece denotado con /**/ que tiene como objeto mostrar los videos dentro de un combobox asociados a las herramientas del primer combobox,  tan solo  me muestra los dos combobox pero el primero ya no me trae las herramientas y el segundo tampoco me trae el registro de los videos asociados al primer combobox.

```
<%@page import="javax.servlet.jsp.tagext.TryCatchFinally"%> 
<%@page language="java" contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.*"%> 
<!DOCTYPE html>
<%
 String herr=null;  
 String vid=null;  
  if(request.getParameter("cboherr")!=null){  
   herr=request.getParameter("cboherr");
  }
  if(request.getParameter("cbovid")!=null){  
   herr=request.getParameter("cbovid");
  }   
  out.print(herr);
  out.print(vid); 
try{
            Connection cn=null;
            Statement cmd=null;
            Statement cmd2=null;  
            Statement cmd3=null;
            ResultSet rs=null;
            ResultSet rs2=null;  
            ResultSet rs3=null;
            String usuario="root";  
            String password="";  
            String basedatos="hcmsoftware";
            String servidor="localhost"; 
            String puerto="3306";  
            String url="jdbc:mysql://"+servidor+":"+puerto+"/"+basedatos;
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

            cn=DriverManager.getConnection(url,usuario,password);
            cmd=cn.createStatement();
            cmd2=cn.createStatement();
            cmd3=cn.createStatement();
    
            String sql2="Select * from herramientas";
            rs2=cmd2.executeQuery(sql2);
%>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body bgcolor="beige">
        <h1 style="text-align: center">Listado_de_Videos</h1>
        <p style="text-align: center">(Búsqueda_general_por_herramienta)</p>
        <hr align="center" width="126%;">
        <form action="" method="post">
            <table width="50%" border="0">  
                <tr>
                    <td width="26%">Seleccione herramienta:</td>  
                    <td width="80%">  
                        <select name="cboherr" id="cboherr" onchange="submit()" > 
                               <option value="">--Seleccione-- </option>                                 
                        
                          <% while(rs2.next()){%>            
                            <option value="<%=rs2.getString(1)%>"><%=rs2.getString(2)%></option> 
                             
                            
                      <%}%>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                    <td width="25%"> </td>
<!-- ***** Cuando incluyo este código que tiene como objeto seguir trayendo las herramientas con sus respectivos videos, no me trae ni las herramientas ni sus correspondientes videos que también aparecen en un combobox *****  -->
     <%  
         String sql3="Select * from videos where idherram='"+herr+"'";
            rs3=cmd3.executeQuery(sql3);
     %>
                    <td width="26%">Seleccione video:</td>  <!-- <td width="33%">  -->
                    <td width="80%">  <!--  <td width="42%"> -->
                        <select name="cbovid" id="cbovid" onchange="submit()" >  
                               <option value="">--Seleccione-- </option>                                 
                        
                          <% while(rs3.next()){%>            
                            <option value="<%=rs3.getString(1)%>"><%=rs3.getString(2)%></option> 
                                            
                      <%}%>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                    <td width="25%"> </td>
<!-- ********************************************************************  - ->

           </tr>
         </table>
                       
      </form>
    
        <% 
            
            if(herr!=null){  
            String sql="Select videos.idvideo, videos.nombrevideo, herramientas.herramienta,videos.enlacegit, videos.enlacevideo FROM videos INNER JOIN herramientas ON videos.idherram= herramientas.idherram and videos.idherram='"+herr+"'";             rs=cmd.executeQuery(sql); 

        
     %>
         <br> 
           <table border="3" width="80%" name="tabla"> 
               <thead>
                   <tr>
                       <th>Id_Video</th>
                       <th>Nombre_Video</th>
                       <th>Nombre_Herramienta</th>
                       <th>Enlace_Git</th>
                       <th>Enlace_Video</th>
                    </tr>
               </thead>
               <tbody>  
                   <%while(rs.next()){ %>
                   <tr>
                       <td style="text-align: center"><%=rs.getString(1)%></td>
                       <td style="text-align: center"><%=rs.getString(2)%></td>
                       <td style="text-align: center"><%=rs.getString(3)%></td>
                       <td style="text-align: center"><a href="<%=rs.getString(4)%>" target="_blank"><%=rs.getString(4)%></a></td> 
                       <td style="text-align: center"><a href="<%=rs.getString(5)%>" target="_blank"><%=rs.getString(5)%></a></td>  
                   </tr>
                    <% } %>
                </tbody>    
                </table>
                
                    <% }  
                  cn.close();
                        }
                 catch(Exception ex){
                 out.println(ex.getMessage());
                 }
                    %> 
    </body>
</html>
```

En el siguiente video explico a profundidad el problema que se me presenta:

https://youtu.be/UBNDOpHg86s
Atentamente

Hernán Martínez